# Color specific treeview item using WIN32 API (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, treeview, common-controls

I wanted to create a tree view where specific items have a different back & text colors.
I did found the following solution in the internet: [Win32 Custom Draw Treeview Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805801/win32-custom-draw-treeview-control), but here they color each item according to its level.
This is close to what I want, but I want to color just a specific treeview item regardless of its level, lets say by its TVITEM handle or its HTREEITEM.

Is it possible to do such a thing using the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message?
If not, how can I do such a thing?

Edit:
I've been trying to use the item's `lParam` in order to identify the treeview item, but the items remain invisible for some reason.
Here is my function which is supposed to handle the custom draw:

```
/*
This function will custom draw a tree view
Input: (LRESULT*) res = To store the result (by reference, to be stored)
       (HWND) window = The handled window
       (LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW) item = The item to draw
       (TVITEM) tvItem = The tv item that should be custom drawn
Output: (BOOL) TRUE if should use the stored value, otherwise FALSE
*/
BOOL customDrawTreeView(LRESULT* res, HWND window, LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW item, TVITEM tvItem)
{
    switch (item->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        *res = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        return TRUE;
        break;
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        if (tvItem.lParam == item->nmcd.lItemlParam)
        {
            item->clrTextBk = 0x383838;
            item->clrText = RGB(255, 255, 255);
            *res = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
            return TRUE;
        }

        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You can draw the TreeView however you want. So what is stopping you from doing what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can attach information to the tree item using the `TVITEM::lParam` member. This value is sent with the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message in the `nmcd.lItemlParam` member of the `NMTVCUSTOMDRAW` struct.

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution but I appear to have another problem: The CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT case in my switch statement appears to never be reached. Do you have any idea why would that happen?

Comment: The CDDS_PREPAINT case is always the one that's reached, even tho the tree view **does** contain items

Comment: Managed to figure it out but it still does not do what I want. The tree view remains empty for some reason, even tho my code is reached and the ```clrTextBk``` & ```clrText``` are set, the items remain invisible. Can you please look at the edit of my question?

Comment: Managed to figure it out (I had to use the SetWindowLongPtr function in both switch cases). Thanks a lot for your help.